# Configuring AWS Sagemaker to Return HTTP Status Codes

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-sagemaker

I currently have a model successfully deployed via AWS Sagemaker's Real-Time Inference, which I configured using the instructions found [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container). The model tries to return a JSON along with a response status.

Both the JSON and response status contain information about whether the model successfully ran or if the model had some issue (whether with the inputs to the model). To invoke the model, I use the AWS Python SDK directly, as I do not want the model to be accessed publicly:

```
sm_runtime = boto3.client("sagemaker-runtime", region_name=region)
result = sm_runtime.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName = endpoint_name,
        Body = body, 
        ContentType = content_type,  
        Accept = accept, 
    )
```

The model works well and returns expected JSON if the response status is 2xx. However, when I try to return an error message, I set the response status to 4xx.

Here is a rough code snippet from `flask_wrapper.py`:

```
response_status = 400
out = io.StringIO()
try: 
    results = model.predict(input) # This outputs as a Python dict
    if 'error' not in results: 
        response_status = 200
    json.dump(results, out, indent=2)
except Exception as e:
    json.dump({'error_type': f'{type(e)}', 'error': str(e)}, out, indent=2)
result = out.getvalue()
return flask.Response(response=result, status=response_status, mimetype="application/json")
```

I have two questions regarding how AWS Sagemaker handles HTTP response status codes that I return in `flask_wrapper.py`:

1. Given the snippet above, I would expect that if my model outputs a dictionary with 'error' or otherwise hits another exception, it'll return a 400 with a helpful message about the error. However, whenever the endpoint is invoked through SageMaker's endpoint, it'll return a 500 without any further response. For comparison, I've tried running this locally by running the Docker container and posting to it locally, and I'll get back the response_status I set. Is it default behavior for SageMaker to take any 4xx from the flask.Response() and turn that into a 500 Internal Server Error when it responds to a request?
2. If I try some other response_status (say 299) to get around this, I can get the error JSON to be returned. However, I find that it will return a response_status of 200. Again, is this default behavior or is there some way to configure this?

Thanks!